# Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS stops working

Tags: lts, ubuntu-tweak

I'm not a master but also not a beginner in the linux system,
I've installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on dual boot with windows 10 and I've been facing a big issue in the Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. The issue is that the complete OS stops working, like not a single click and it never starts again, I've tried waiting for 10 hrs, the only solution is that I have to press the power key of my laptop and start the laptop again. 
My laptop is powered by core i5-6200U 2.30 GHz x4
4 GB RAM
Intel HD Graphics 520
GNOME version: 3.28.2
This issue mostly happens while debugging the android application in my phone (no emulator) or sometimes while working on terminal.
I have some Gnome shell extensions installed, can this be the main cause of problem?
Also I've install the CPU Power Manager to overclock my CPU.
I'm expecting a big help from here or I'll switch to manjaro, as I've tried reinstalled the complete OS.

Comment: Inspecting system log may help. Try the command `journalctl -b-1 | tail -n100` after such a "forced" reboot.

Comment: I think your attitude needs some adjustment. If you want to switch, switch, the community has no obligation to help you: everyone who takes the time to drop you a reply does so out of their own free time. Now, has the problem occurred only while over clocking? I'd say it goes against all conventional wisdom to overclock a laptop, the cooling restraints are simply too tight, and if it has only happened while you're overclocking, I'd say that's the cause

Comment: You have three problems. 1) small amount of RAM, and probably too small swap, 2) you've overclocked your laptop, 3) you may also have installed a defective GNOME Shell extension. Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.